# Get parent class property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript class that has a method that uses jQuery to send an Ajax request and handle the response.

The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to get the properties of the initial, parent class from within the jQuery functions. I have tried `$(this).parent()` but this doesn't get what I need for some reason.

My code is below. Can anyone tell me how to get to the base class from this loop?

```
function companiesPage()
{
    this.childCategoriesSelectid = '#childCategoryid';

    this.setChildCategories = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $.each(data.childCategories, function()
                {
                    $($(this).parent().childCategoriesSelectid)//problem here
                    .append(
                        $('<option></option>')
                        .attr('value', this.childCategoryid)
                        .text(this.name)
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `.attr('value', ..)`. Use `.val(..)` instead!

Comment: The HTML doesn't matter. If I try to alert() it out, it shows "undefined" so its not there obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent()` is for DOM traversal. What you have is a scoping problem.

The `this` keyword does not always references the same object when entering a new function scope. That is the case when using jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method which will set `this` to the object/element being iterated.

Looks like you're using a constructor-instance pattern, so you just have store a reference to the original object that the `this` keyword referenced to (the instance) through a var declaration. This reference will remain unchangeable in the scope chain:

```
function companiesPage()
{
    var _this = this; //stores a reference to this instance object
    this.childCategoriesSelectid = '#childCategoryid';

    this.setChildCategories = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $.each(data.childCategories, function()
                {
                    $(_this.childCategoriesSelectid) //NO problem here :)
                    .append(
                        $('<option></option>')
                        .val(this.childCategoryid)
                        .text(this.name)
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to access any of your instance's public methods and properties anywhere inside of your instance.

ps. Instanceables/Constructors usually have the first letter upper-cased, by convention.

Answer (score 1):

### Capture `this` before asynchronous Ajax call

Ajax success handler is asynchronously executed hence looses its callee context (or scope). You have to capture `this` free variable and use captured variable within function closure.

#### It seems you're expecting `this` to have two meanings

1. when you use `$(this).parent()...` you're expecting `this` to be some `HTMLDOMElement`
2. when you use `this.name` you're expecting `this` to be an object item in your `data` (likely array).

### Solution of getting object instance reference

It becomes obvious that companiesPage is your class (should be Pascal cased and not camel cased). Hence the use of `this` within. You likely create it by:

```
var obj = new CompaniesPage();
obj.setChildCategories();
```

your code should then look like this:

```
var CompaniesPage = function()
{
    // keep this as public object property
    this.childCategoriesSelectId = "#childCategoryid";

    // keep this as public object method
    this.setChildCategories = function() {
        // private reference to object instance for later reuse
        var me = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.url, // not sure where this one's coming from
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.childCategories, function() {
                    $(me.childCategoriesSelectId).append(
                        $('<option></option>')
                            .attr('value', this.childCategoryid)
                            .text(this.name)
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

### Additional optimisation of your class

You also have to realise that the way that you've defined your class-level method is not memory efficient because individual object instances won't share the same method but would rather have each their own which reflects on memory resources especially when you'd create several instances of the same class.

This is an optimised version of your class:

```
var CompaniesPage = function() {
    // keep this as public object property
    this.childCategoriesSelectId = "#childCategoryid";
}

CompaniesPage.prototype.setChildCategories = function() {
    // private reference to me as object instance
    var me = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: this.url, // not sure where this one's coming from
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.childCategories, function() {
                $(me.childCategoriesSelectId).append(
                    $('<option></option>')
                        .attr('value', this.childCategoryid)
                        .text(this.name)
                );
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: True, but in this case he's using `this` in the `$.each()` to refer to the current item in the iteration. *(I wish people would just use parameters!)*

Comment: ...actually, I have no idea what he wants `this` to be for the `$(this).parent()` call. I don't see any `this` in the code that would make sense.

Comment: @user1689607: Exactly what I saw as well. We can't really see where context is coming from. I edited my answer to reflect this fact. From the code provided it's hard to know where either `data` or `this` should be coming from. More importantly `data` as that's the one that's used within `each` iterator function.